# Repeater, Datalist in ASP vs PHP

Tags: php

Can anyone give me some suggestion please. In ASP we can use datalist and repeater control to repeate the rows but how can we do similar in PHP.

I am designing a private message page for the similair as inbox page.

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop construct. For example:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['name']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['email']); ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/crashcourse.php). It has [{foreach}](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.foreach.php) construct.